# The <sequential> type doesn't support nested text data ("\")

Tags: for-loop, ant, sequential, ant-contrib

I am executing an ANT target where I write to copy a zip file from 1 folder to another folder. For copying a list of files I have used a "for" loop. While executing this I am facing this issue:

```
The <sequential> type doesn't support nested text data ("\").
```

My script in the target is as follows:

```
<for param="MyZipParameter" list="${FilesInsideZipFile}" delimiter=";">
       <sequential>
          <if>
            <matches string="@{MyZipParameter}" pattern="UpdateSite*" />
              <then>
```

I am facing the issue during starting of "if" block in the script. I thought some invisible characters might be there and I have removed the script and without copying I have typed the script again, but still same the issue occurs during execution.

This totally blocked my work and I could not find any clue on this. Please help and provide your inputs.

Comment: There isn't much to say here; somewhere in your script there's a loose ```\``` and you'll have to remove it. Regarding the rest of your script, Ant has a robust catalog of `fileset` and `dirset` functions that can probably handle what you're trying to do without any looping or conditional statements. I highly recommend staying away from ant-contrib if possible.

Comment: Sorry, since my script was too long and I was not found earlier and it took me a bit long time to find it out. Was having a "\" in my script. Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: I had a loose end bracket from cutting and pasting.